# Modifying a function to account for inhomogeneous boundary conditions? This is used for solving a pde and I want to know the origin of this method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I found a pdf which I have linked [HERE](https://atmos.washington.edu/%7Ebreth/classes/AM585/lect/FS_2DPoisson.pdf) related to solving a 2nd order PDE and it stated on the second page for the discrete approach to solving the PDE that "*$f(x_i,y_j)$ is suitably modified along the rows/columns neighboring a boundary to account for the inhomogeneous boundary conditions*" and I saw in the associated script found [HERE](https://atmos.uw.edu/%7Ebreth/classes/AM585/matlab/lect/pois_FD_FFT_2D.m) that it performs these modifications where it comments "Correct for Dirichlet BCs" which I have pasted below:

```
  L = 1;        % Domain size
  Ne = 16;      % Extended-domain gridpoints...should be a power of 2
  h = 2*L/Ne;   % Grid spacing
  m = Ne/2 - 1; % Number of interior gridpoints in original domain

  x = h*(1:m);
  y = h*(1:m);
  
  f = 4*ones(m,m);
% Correct for Dirichlet BCs
  u0y = y.^2;
  u1y = 1 + y.^2;
  ux0 = x.^2;
  ux1 = 1 + x.^2;
  f(:,1) = f(:,1) - ux0'/h^2;
  f(:,m) = f(:,m) - ux1'/h^2;
  f(1,:) = f(1,:) - u0y/h^2;
  f(m,:) = f(m,:) - u1y/h^2;
```

Which would look like if I took the PDE:
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy} = f(x_i,y_j);f(x_i,y_j) = 4; 0<x<1, 0<y<1 \\ u(x,0) = x^2,u(x,1) = 1+x^2,\\u(0,y) = y^2,u(1,y) = 1+y^2$$
and I did this to modify $f(x_i,y_j)$:
$$f(x_i,y_1=\frac{1}{8})\leftarrow f(x_i,y_1=\frac{1}{8}) - \frac{u(x_i,y_0=0)}{h^2}= 4-\frac{x^2}{h^2}\\
f(x_i,y_m=\frac{7}{8})\leftarrow f(x_i,y_m=\frac{7}{8}) - \frac{u(x_i,y_{m+1}=1)}{h^2}=4-\frac{1+x^2}{h^2}\\
f(x=\frac{1}{8},y_j)\leftarrow f(x_1=\frac{1}{8},y_j) - \frac{u(x_0=0,y_j)}{h^2}=4-\frac{y^2}{h^2}\\
f(x=\frac{7}{8},y_j)\leftarrow f(x_m=\frac{7}{8},y_j) - \frac{u(x_{m+1}=1,y_j)}{h^2} = 4-\frac{1+y^2}{h^2}$$
where division by $h^2$ is supposed to be to account for the different units i.e. some function $x^2$ with unit spacing h would have units of $h^2$ while $f(x,y)=4$ would be unitless, so we make this division so they can be subtracted since they need the same units to add or subtract.

So it looks like "suitably modified" simply means to subtract off the Boundary Conditions. What I want to know is if there is a name for or source referencing this methodology of subtracting these Dirichlet Boundary Conditions from their neighboring values, or if there is a proof which shows how this works out. for obtaining the solution in the end.

NOTE: The linked full script obtains the solution in this and it utilizes the Fourier Transform method to obtain the solution after these modifications have been applied.